# Match an event in two datafiles if the timing for the event differs in the datafiles due to the different sampling rate

Tags: r, time

I need to export stimuli codes from one datafile to another, the problem is that the timing for the stimuli onset is recorded with different sampling rate in datafiles A and B, which is why finding the exact match in time is not possible. So I need to write an R code that would link the timepoint for a SCode from dataset A with a timepoint in dataset B that is the closest to it and to create an SCode variable in dataset B with this Scode value. But so far I haven't found a way to do that.

Example:

Dataset A: Contains timepoint of the stimuli onset and the stimuli identifier codes:

```
Time <- c("17:02:54.064", "17:03:08.004", "17:03:23.125")
SCode <- c(11, 12, 22)
```

Dataset B: Contains 8 timepoints for each second, none of the time points is an exact match in terms of ms to the timepoints in dataset A:

```
Time <- c("17:02:54.022", "17:02:54.147", "17:02:54.272", "17:02:54.397", "17:02:54.522", "17:02:54.647", "17:02:54.772", "17:02:54.897", "17:03:08.022", "17:03:08.147", "17:03:08.272", "17:03:08.397", "17:03:08.522", "17:03:08.647", "17:03:08.772", "17:03:08.897", "17:03:23.022", "17:03:23.147", "17:03:23.272", "17:03:23.397", "17:03:23.522", "17:03:23.647", "17:03:23.772", "17:03:23.897")
```

In the end I need to have an SCode variable in dataset B with the relevant stimuli codes (e.g., 11 for all timepoints from 17:02:54.064 to 17:03:08.004).

I would appreciate any suggestions/hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Convert *Time* to datetime class using *anytime*, then merge on "nearest" using *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)  # to merge on nearest
library(anytime)     # to convert datetime

#convert input into a data.table
d1 <- data.table(Time = c("17:02:54.064", "17:03:08.004", "17:03:23.125"),
                 SCode = c(11, 12, 22))

d2 <- data.table(Time = c("17:02:54.022", "17:02:54.147", "17:02:54.272", 
                          "17:02:54.397", "17:02:54.522", "17:02:54.647", 
                          "17:02:54.772", "17:02:54.897", "17:03:08.022", 
                          "17:03:08.147", "17:03:08.272", "17:03:08.397", 
                          "17:03:08.522", "17:03:08.647", "17:03:08.772", 
                          "17:03:08.897", "17:03:23.022", "17:03:23.147", 
                          "17:03:23.272", "17:03:23.397", "17:03:23.522", 
                          "17:03:23.647", "17:03:23.772", "17:03:23.897"))

#covnert to datetime with milliseconds.
#prefix with any date, e.g. today's date, so it converts to datetime object.
d1[, tt := anytime(paste("2022-03-14", Time)) ]
d2[, tt := anytime(paste("2022-03-14", Time)) ]

#then merge on nearest
setkey(d1, tt)
setkey(d2, tt)

d1[ d2, roll = "nearest" ]
#            Time SCode                  tt       i.Time
# 1: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.022
# 2: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.147
# 3: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.272
# 4: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.397
# 5: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.522
# 6: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.647
# 7: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.772
# 8: 17:02:54.064    11 2022-03-14 18:02:54 17:02:54.897
# 9: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.022
#10: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.147
#11: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.272
#12: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.397
#13: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.522
#14: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.647
#15: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.772
#16: 17:03:08.004    12 2022-03-14 18:03:08 17:03:08.897
#17: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.022
#18: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.147
#19: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.272
#20: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.397
#21: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.522
#22: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.647
#23: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.772
#24: 17:03:23.125    22 2022-03-14 18:03:23 17:03:23.897
#            Time SCode                  tt       i.Time
```